# Shell Scripting - Reading properties file and Addition (mathematical) of two variables

Tags: linux, shell, properties, scripting, addition

I am writing a program that will operate on a loop and I need to increment time milliseconds that get passed in as a variable. It's for timestamp calculation.

I have found out how to change properties in a properties file like this:

```
sed -i "/exampleKey=/ s/=.*/=newExampleValue1/" test.properties
```

But before that I want to be able to get the currentExampleValue1 and perform addition on it..

like this:

```
exampleKey=1000

//Get Current value here (1000)

sed -i "/exampleKey=/ s/=.*/= (current value + 500) /" test.properties
```

so that the properties file is now:

```
exampleKey=1500
```

Is there a simple way to do this in Linux? I should note that I'm extremely new to shell scripting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sed` can't do math. Perl can:

```
perl -i~ -pe '/exampleKey=/ and s/=(.*)/"=" . ($1 + 500)/e' test.properties
```

- `-p` reads the file line by line and prints each after processing
- `/e` evaluates the replacement part as code.

You can use a look-behind assertion for shorter code:

```
s/(?<==)(.*)/$1 + 500/e
```

i.e. replace everything preceded by `=` by itself + 500.

Comment: This is excellent. I have been searching and searching... (apparently in the wrong places) for a way to do this. This works perfectly. Thank you. Do you know how to easily read the properties file and get the value as well?  I.e. newKey=someValue    and later in the code "The value is $someValue.."

Comment: To ask a new question, open a new question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`, this would be:

```
awk -F= '$1=="exampleKey"{$2+=500}1'
```

The field delimiter is set to `=` character, such that `$2` points to the value you want to increase.

If you have GNU awk, you may want to use the option `-i inplace` to perform the change directly on the file (similar `-i` for sed).